# What solutions are available to visualize Json data on a dashboard?

Tags: data-visualization

I have an application on a protected network and want to visualize levels on a dashboard. I want to send the data as a JSON to a webhook which then processes and visualizes the data. I don't want to run my own web server.

I have already looked at some tools. Most of them I have found so far, there is no way to create a webhook. They require a database or cloud storage. Primarily I need the possibility to display several pie charts on one dashboard. In the best case a gauge. The solution should cost a maximum of $50 per month.

I've only just found a solution. https://www.dasheroo.com

Does anyone know of a similar solution I need to be able to send the data to the service via web request.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. E.g. if you "found a solution", there must be a reason why you want us to tell you alternatives: what features do you need, why does Dasheroo not fit? What about the price (how much may it cost)?